# How did Paco use the ceiling to hide the book?

Tags: plot-explanation, you

In the Netflix series YOU, the episode 9 (Candance) we see that Paco returns a book to Beck while Joe is out, and he says that he forgot the book was still in the ceiling. He explains that Joe had told him every apartment in the building has a secret hiding place in the ceiling just above the toilet.

How was Paco able to access it? From the other episodes where Joe accesses the ceiling we see that the height is just right for him but Paco is a kid, so how is he able to access the ceiling?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't he access the ceiling panel? Eve Beck's height was not enough to reach the ceiling and she uses a toilet seat. Why Can't Paco do the same?

I have a toilet with such pannel and usually, they are not that high and I guess a stool, etc can help a kid to reach it easily.

Comment: "Why can't he access the ceiling panel?" - I don't think there's any reason why he can't access the ceiling panel. Maybe this would best be asked as a separate question or as a clarifying comment on the question.

Comment: @user133469 it's hypophora